# When the Microsoft Graph beta can be released

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph beta unsupported create Org Contacts.

Is the new version can support create Org Contacts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should ask Microsoft..

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
Based on your latest response it looks like you need Org Contacts.  Creation of organizational contacts is currently not supported.  Please vote for the following ask on Uservoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17617309-make-it-possible-to-create-organizational-contacts

Also it would be great to understand your scenario as to why your app needs to create organizational contacts.

Comment: Yes, very correct, I am talking about the contract,The current version does not support create Org contacts.  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact